# Python - Mac - Pygame in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I have installed pygame, and on my Python menu, it shows me:

```
pygame 2.0.0.dev6 (SDL 2.0.10, python 3.8.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Whenever I look at it on my Terminal, it says it is downloaded.

However, when I open PyCharm or Visual Studio Code and type in:

```py
import pygame
```

It comes up with this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.'
```

I have tried everything from uninstalling everything to watching all kinds of videos on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your interpreter in Pycharm is not set to the right interpreter. Follow this:-

Step-1: you have to go to the edit configuration button situated at the topmost right screen of your pycharm window and after clicking on it select the interpreter you want from the list.

Step-2: Go to system settings (in Windows) or system preferences (in mac) and then select a project interpreter from the dropdown menu. From there, you can change the interpreter settings as well as install packages from the '+' sign. In this, you can also see the modules you have installed into the interpreter selected so choose the interpreter where you can see the pygame installed.

[image: Somewhat like this]